# Node.js oracledb query of BLOB returns null

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I have problem with querying BLOBs using NodeJS oracledb. I am using oracledb library 6.2.0.

When I query table containing the blob, I receive NULL instead of Buffer or Lob object (I tried setting fetching Lobs as buffer), but nothing works, I get NULL, when in SQL Developer I clearly see and can download value. Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Interesting thing is that some blobs in some tables are being returned, but I am not able to analyse the key by which it is being returned.

Comment: Without knowing any of your code, and without any of your sample data to check, we can only guess what might be wrong.  And that guess is that you are connecting to a different database (or user), or haven't committed some data in the SQL Developer session so it is not visible to the node-oracledb user.  Or you have set CLOBS to be fetched as Strings but not set BLOBS to be fetched as Buffers. Read the [node-oracledb doc](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#querying-lobs) again and check your code and data.

Comment: I have read the doc several times. I have resolved the issue by going through original recordset and selecting each row with blob individually in separate statement. That indicates that there might be some cache/memory settings involved, but there is literally none information about that anywhere.

Comment: If you share an example, we can help more.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example